# Accessing and changing a value of an xml element in Android java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a Webview and Advert in my xml:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

How do I access `adView` in my java code and check the value of `app:adSize`?

How do I change its value to `"LARGE_BANNER"` so that the Webview automatically resizes?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the AdView in the code. From the right context call findViewById and assign it to an AdView Object

```
AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

To get the AdSize

```
AdSize adSize = adView.getAdSize();
```

To set an AdSize

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.LARGE_BANNER);
```

Comment: The line `AdSize adSize = adView.getAdSize();` crashes the program. This is strange as I am having similar problems with my full page adverts see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690250/interstitialad-crashes-does-not-display-ad

Comment: Should have added, adView is something, ie it is not null.

Comment: Those are the calls that you would make. It's not the code that you would just copy paste and expect to work. Also if you call findViewById(R.id.adView); from the right context it wouldn't be null in the first place

Comment: @Rewind I hope you got answer to the specific question that you've asked here